# Unable to serialize custom attribute in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, serialization, system.text.json

There is a custom attribute I created that I prescribe to classes for the markup extension.

I used to use the serialization mechanism through Newtonsoft.Json and I want to switch to Text.Json, but I ran into a problem that it throws exceptions when trying to serialize classes that inherit from Attribute

```
public class ConfigNameAttribute : Attribute
  {
    public ConfigNameAttribute(string name, bool enable)
    {
      this.name = name;
      this.enable = enable;
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool enable { get; set; }
  }
```

```
var text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(temp);
```

throws an exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true.'

if you remove Attribute then everything is fine

Comment: The problem is caused by `Attribute.TypeId` returning `GetType()` by default, and System.Text.Json does not support serializing or deserializing `Type` objects.  Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Eur4o.  Json.NET serializes `TypeId` as follows: `"TypeId":"ConfigNameAttribute, 3wduoyfp.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`.

Comment: oh right. for Newtonsoft.Json i write JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
   settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   settings.ContractResolver = new DictionaryAsArrayResolver(new string[] { "TypeId",  }); but for Text.Json I don't find such approach

Comment: found, it was necessary to put the option System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(temp, new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
 IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true
});